# How do I point bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') to my parent theme?

Tags: shortcode, urls, links, directory

I've created a child theme but the parent theme seems to use bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') to point to a lot of CSS and js files, none of which are currently loading.

As I believe the 'stylesheet_directory' is meant to point to the main CSS file directory, my child theme, am I going to have to copy the header into my child theme and update the paths with a different shortcode?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If the parent theme is properly coded, the following code in the child theme functions.php file should load the parent css.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

As for the javascript, I think that if the parent theme loads theme with wp_enqueue_scripts they should work in the child theme.

Comment: Thanks. I've got that in my functions.php files but it looks like the parent theme wasn't properly built. A lot of the links for css and js use bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') which is pointing to the child theme.